# File size grows when modify date to datetime

Tags: sql, date

I'm converting date to datetime in several DBs, but the final file size changes from 300mb to 3gb...anyone knows the reason of that huge growth?

Comment: Propably something with write sets, logging, transactions etc. Which dbms are you using? How many rows per update etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date type size is about 3 bytes, datatime is about 8 bytes. If there is a million records...thats is :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a self-taught database person, so if anyone has a more decent explanation, you should mark that as an answer. Here's what I've learned over the past two years.

(My)SQL is a pessimist by nature; if you change the type and collation of a field, it's going to inflate the size of the table to fit as much data as it'd contain by maximum. (You'd have the same effect of inflating the table size with varchar fields where you change from UTF8_general_ci to UTF8MB4_general_ci).

The difference between changing collation and type is that by changing the type from date to datetime, you're asking your system to generate new data. So today's date stored in a MYSQL datefield is written as `2019-12-12` if you change that to a datetime type, it gets changed to: `2019-12-12 00:00:00`

Changing the type thus adds new data; this data are the hours, minutes and seconds. It's however meaningless (all 00) as there was nothing there in the first place.

So now you have all those 00's in your database for hours, minutes and seconds. That's probably taking up quite a lot of space, but my gut feeling is that it shouldn't inflate your database from 300mb to 3gb.